# How to port forawrd on AWS

Tags: java, sockets, amazon-web-services

I have hosted my simple UDPServer program on AWS Ubuntu 14.04, it's working correctly their, but when i tried accessing it from my system, am not able to connect to it, surely it is, something to do with AWS firewall, so how can i make my UDP traffic to pass through it! And port of my UDP server is 2020.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: This is not programming-related. I think this question might be better suited for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also looking for possible workaround for this issue, but it's quite easy irrespective of what platform language you are using to develop socket program on AWS EC2, as am using Node.js nginx in my case, this should work for all supporting platforms.

**Configure Security Group**

1. In the AWS console, open the EC2 tab.
2. Select the relevant region and click on Security Group.
3. You should have an default security group if you
   have launched an Elastic Beanstalk instance in that region for your
   app.
4. click on Actions button at top, and select Edit inbound rules.
5. here in Type column select All UDP, or you can set some Custom UDP
   rule as well to listen at your socket port.
6. And there just enter port of your UDP server 2020.

   And that's it!

Note: If something is not working, check the "Events" tab in the Beanstalk application / environments and find out what went wrong.